# Angular: (ngFor) How to prevent it from reloading when I remove an item?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a list of images in my page:

```
<img *ngFor="let picture of pictures" [src]="picture.path">
```

The problem is that, every time I remove a picture, the previous list is recreated and all the images are reloaded. How can I prevent it from reloading the images when I remove an item? Is there any alternative for the ngFor directive?

Comment: mmm, if the paths are the same after list regeneration, shouldn't the images be cached?

Comment: You are most probably returning a complete list after deleting an item, instead of just removing an item from the existing list. That way it will not recreate.

Comment: The images are loaded from an external service. I'll try the "trackBy" option to see if I can improve the performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `trackBy` as explained [here](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5)

> We can help Angular to track which items added or removed by providing
>   a trackBy function. The trackBy function takes the index and the
>   current item as arguments and needs to return the unique identifier
>   for this item. Now when you change the collection, Angular can track
>   which items have been added or removed according to the unique
>   identifier and create or destroy only the things that changed.

```
<img *ngFor="let picture of pictures; trackBy: trackImageId" [src]="picture.path">

trackImageId(index: number, picture: PictureModel) {
        return picture.id;
    }
```

Comment: This is amazing. It works like a charm. I don't understand why my question has so many downvotes. I guess this is a trivial question for most of people.

Comment: Happy it helped ! I think you're getting downvoted because you are asking for an "alternative" instead of searching the framework documentation.

Comment: Hey, what purpose does index:number serve in the function? Why is picture.id being returned? Should that be called picture.index?